Distribute spacing with negative gap
I want that my cards inside of flexbox distribute evenly depending on the height of my div like in this gif, but I can't find a way to do it. Because gap can't be negative, margin top auto can't go to negative either and the other options modify the height of my card.
figma exemple
I need that option because the number of cards change and I want that all of it to display on the screen.
This is my actual code:
<div id="Page2">
    <template id="card">
        <div class="cardDesign">
            <h2></h2>
            <img id="CardLogo" src="/img/kidebit_logo_outline.png" alt="">
            <img id="NFCicon" src="img/NFC.png" alt="">
        </div>
    </template>
</div>

#Page2 {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 50vh;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
    padding-top: 200px;
    max-width: 332px;
}

.cardDesign {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: flex-start;
    padding: 18px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 182px;
    margin-top: -140px;
}


Try this:
<div className="cards-wrapper">
  <div className="card"></div>
  <div className="card"></div>
  <div className="card"></div>
  <div className="card"></div>
  <div className="card"></div>
</div>

.cards-wrapper{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.card{
    background: linear-gradient(179deg, #e5e2da 0%, #8b8b8b 100%);
    width: 200px;
    height: 30vh;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 1px #ababab;
}

.card:not(:first-child){
    margin-top: -15vh;
}



Thanks for the response, but I think I should give up this idea, I think it's not possible. What I wanted was for the flexbox to be space-between so that the cards could be distributed over the available height, but from what I've found it doesn't work if the container is lower than the total height of the cards, they don't stack like on my gif.

Good answers include some explanation, not just code
